# Generating private key in a file using certreq in powershell

Tags: powershell, csr, certreq

I am using a powershell script to create Certificate Signing Request (CSR) using certreq. I need the private key in a file but the script is not generating that. I tried looking the documentation of certreq and other resources but found nothing. In INF setting I am setting Exportable = TRUE. here is the setting

```
$settingsInf = "
[Version] 
Signature=`"`$Windows NT`$ 
[NewRequest] 
KeyLength =  2048
Exportable = TRUE 
MachineKeySet = TRUE 
SMIME = FALSE
RequestType =  PKCS10 
ProviderName = `"Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider`" 
ProviderType =  12
HashAlgorithm = sha256
;Variables
Subject = `"CN={{CN}},CN={{CN2}},O={{O}},DC={{DC}},DC={{DC2}}`"
[Extensions]
{{SAN}}
```

Another solution I tried is to use openssl to get private key and CSR. In this solution I am getting both private key and CSR but when I submit the CSR to CA then it throws following error

```
 "message" : "Invalid Subject DN.  The requested Subject DN is not compatible with the issuing CA.",
```

I am using openssl as follows

```
$subject = "`"/CN=$cn/CN=$cn2/O=$o/DC=$dc/DC=$dc2'"

openssl req -new -key $privateKeyPath -rand $randPath -subj $subject -out $csrPath
```

The Certificate Authority DN is as follows

```
"issuer_dn" : "CN=usa,O=SE,DC=abc,DC=com",
```

any suggestion to either get private key using certreq or why CA is throwing error when using openssl. Thanks

Comment: > why CA is throwing error.  
 Does removing `,CN={{CN2}}` or `/CN=$cn2` help?  Maybe replacing `,O={{O}},DC={{DC}},DC={{DC2}}` or `/O=$o/DC=$dc/DC=$dc2` with hard-coded  `,O=SE,DC=abc,DC=com`.  Worth a check.

Comment: Hi, I tried the hardcoded as well same result the exception

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. may be it will help someone else.

It appears that some CA require subject in a particular order which is not documented (Super Annoying).

The CA I was connected to require $subject in following way

```
$subject = "`"/DC=$dc2/DC=$dc/O=$o/CN=$cn2/CN=$cn'"
```

using subject like this in generating CSR is accepted by CA.